Using parallel transport to construct geodesically convex regions
Let $M$ be a manifold and let $\Omega \subset M$ define a geodesically convex region. You can think of $M = \mathbb{S}^2$ and $\Omega$ as a spherical cap contained in a hemisphere as an example. I am trying to find a concept which would be the analogue of the Minkowski addition of convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for manifolds.
A natural idea would be to consider "fattening" the boundary $\partial \Omega$ by means of some parallel transport of the radial geodesics, but I do not know how to connect these concepts. Also, how could one guarantee the new region would be geodesically convex? Perhaps there might be some way to prove the existence of an homotopy which transforms a strictly geodesically convex region of a manifold into another also strictly geodesically convex region, whilst passing through strictly geodesically convex regions as the homotopy evolves.  If there is a construction of the type that is already known, I have not been able to find it.

It is hard to tell what are you asking. My suggestion is to list axiomatically the properties that you want such 'addition' to satisfy. Most likely, one can prove that it simply does not exist.

Maybe then you are not ready for such challenges and should learn more differential geometry before trying to come up with a novel construction. I am not trying to discourage you (it is good that you are thinking about some nonstandard problems), but learning comes first.

One natural way of defining Minkowski "addition" on a complete Riemannian manifold $M$ would, I think, be the following: Let $\Omega \subset M$ be a compact domain with Lipschitz boundary and, for each $x \in \partial\Omega$, let $L_x \subset T_xM$ be a convex set that contains $0$ in its interior. The for each $t > 0$, you can define $$\Omega + tL = \{ \exp_x tv\ :\ x \in \partial\Omega,\ v \in L_x\}. $$ It is now natural to study the volume of $\Omega+tL$ for $t$ smalll. This has been studied extensively when $L_x$ is the unit ball in $T_xM$. I'm not sure about when $L$ is an arbitrary convex body.
